# How to get All Tagss of a Blog Wordpress without a Loop?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I am coding a Blog on a website. On this page, I want to display the list of all tags created the user to display, in a way that when user click on each tags, related posts would be displayed.
Whatever I found on Codex, is needs to be placed inside the loop, and it would only return tags related to a post.

 Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_tags( $args ) and customise the $args accordingly the way you want. It also doesn`t have to be in the loop.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags